# azure website - file system storage

Tags: file, azure, web, system, storage

I am hosting a website on Azure. I have a simple php file uploaded there to display some data that gets posted (via http) to my php. When I see my dashboard I see that the file system storage keeps increasing for no known reason. When i monitor it in the night its around 8 Mb and in the mor it has grown to 18.8 Mb .
Can anyone explain , whats going on ?

If this happens then i will exceed the 1 GB limit soon.

Please note : the http post overwrites the same file every time and the http post is a json message of size around a 1kb.

Comment: Is this only one file that gets uploaded and kept temporarily, or do you need to persist this data?

Comment: Hi, The last posted data will be saved in that file. The size of that will be hardly couple of Kbs.

Answer (score 3):

Your Azure file system storage should not grow unless you save some data on the disk (text files etc.). The best way to check content of your disk is to connect to your Azure website with Windows WebMatrix and check entire remote content.

Please bear in mind that increasing number of instances will affect your file storage system in Share mode. How many instances do you have? And what happen to file system storage usage if you increase / decrease number of instances?

**EDIT**

What also matters is number of files, their size and file system cluster size.

Example: 
With file system cluster size **4K**

- 1 file 100K take **~100K** of disk space
- 100 files 1K each takes **~400K** of disk space

With file system cluster size **64K**

- 1 file 100K take **~128K** of disk space
- 100 files 1K each takes **~6400K** of disk space

I could not find much information about Windows Azure Website disk cluster size. However, I believe it might be set to some bigger disk cluster size in order to improve performance (some evidence that bigger disk cluster size improves performance can be found in [Configuring Disks in Azure for More Performance](http://tk.azurewebsites.net/2012/08/) article.)

**EDIT 2**

I performed a quick test with 200 files 28 bytes each (size of all files ~5K) on Windows Azure Website - Free. Azure disk usage shows **1M**. That indicates Windows Azure Website disk cluster size is **4K**.

Please bear in mind that Windows Azure Website service is still in preview phase so disk cluster size may change.

**EDIT 3**

Another element which can affect your disk space are enabled diagnostics.
[image: Windows Azure Diagnostics]

If you have diagnostics enabled, please disable them for couple of hours (a day) and check if your disk space is still growing.

Comment: Hi Tom, We checked the storage using the webmatrix and it shows a size of 3.6 Mb.  Right now, we have only 1 instance of the website that is running. The website mode is "free".

Comment: Tom, Any reason why the file system storage would keep growing with out any activity ? Is there any logging that azure website does internally and dumps in file storage ?